# Random draw based on dummies (in R)

Tags: r

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), control_1_2017 = c(1, 0, 1, 
0), control_2_2017 = c(1, 0, 1, 0), control_3_2017 = c(1, 1, 
1, 0), control_4_2017 = c(1, 0, 1, 1), control_5_2017 = c(0, 
1, 1, 0), `Ex of desired output` = c("1_2017", "5_2017", "2_2017", 
"4_2017")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I have a dataset with uniques id, in which each column is dummy indicating whether the id can serve as a control in each month.
For each id, I wish to randomly draw a month for which it can serve as control if there is more than a single "1".

If there is a "1" only for a single month, I want to choose that month.

I provided in the last column an example of a desired output (surely, the exact values will depend on the draw). I wish to print out the month that was randomly drawn in the same format as they are in the columns.

I potentially have many months (in more than one year) and various id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `max.col`

```
nm1 <- grep("control_", names(df1), value = TRUE)
sub("control_", "", nm1[max.col(df1[nm1], "random")])
[1] "2_2017" "5_2017" "1_2017" "4_2017"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But how do I make it into a new a column?

Comment: @Rnovice You can assign the output to a column i.e. `df1$new <- sub("control_", "", nm1[max.col(df1[nm1], "random")])`

Comment: I have a related question. I can open a new one if necessary. How can I add a leading zero if the month is < 10? I have only found the answer for decimals.

Comment: @Rnovice You can use `sprintf` i.e. `sprintf("%02d", 1:20)`